# Zoom out issue on mobile devices

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am in the process of building my website and I'm having an issue that I can't figure out how to fix! It's driving me mad!

I have a menu that animates in from the left hand side of the page and is fixed at width 100% and height 100%.

It works fine on on my laptop but when I view it on my iPhone the menu seems to 'zoom out' when the menu is activated.

If anyone could help me with this i would really appreciate it.

CSS

```
nav {
width:100%;
right:100%;
background:#111725;
overflow-x:scroll;
z-index:5;
height:100%;
```

}

JS

```
$("#menuToggle").click(function(){
$("#navToggle").toggleClass('active');
$("main,header,.twitterToggle,.searchToggle").toggleClass('pushLeft');
$("nav").toggleClass('navLeft');
$("nav ul li").toggleClass('fadeUp');
```

});

HTML

```
<div id="menuToggle"><a id="navToggle"><span></span></a>MENU</div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="http://danieljosephdesigns.co.uk/#services">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="http://danieljosephdesigns.co.uk/#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
<li>
<a href="https://twitter.com/danjodesigns" target="_blank" class="twitter"></a>
  <a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/danieljosephdesigns" target="_blank" class="linkedIn"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Rather than linking people to a complete site that might not exist months later when people google this question, we tend to prefer if people try to isolate just the parts of their code that cause the issue, and post those as a complete problem. (As a bonus, following this process can actually help people find the issue sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

Toggle `.is-locked` class on `body` on the click function. So, you jquery code would be.

```
$("#menuToggle").click(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('is-locked');
    $("#navToggle").toggleClass('active');
    $("main,header,.twitterToggle,.searchToggle").toggleClass('pushLeft');
    $("nav").toggleClass('navLeft');
    $("nav ul li").toggleClass('fadeUp');
});
```

And add the following CSS

```
.is-locked {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Also remove `overlow-x:scroll` from `nav`.